# Quick Launch highlight current page

Tags: page-layout, quick-launch

I have created a custom page layout with 3 zones. The left zone has uses the following code to render the navigation. (Managed navigation).

```
<SharePoint:SPNavigationManager id="ContentPageNavigationManager" runat="server" QuickLaunchControlId="ContentPageQuickLaunchMenu"  
                        ContainedControl="QuickLaunch"
                        EnableViewState="false">
                            <asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider" ShowStartingNode="True" id="ContentPageQuickLaunchSiteMap" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" runat="server" />
                            <SharePointWebControls:AspMenu id="ContentPageQuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="ContentPageQuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="3" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="" />
                        </SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
```

I want to highlight the current page in quick launch navigation but at present it defaults to the first item in navigation menu. I want to highlight "complete a timesheet" on left nav but it defaults to first item...

not sure which property in AspMenu control that sets this value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any option in the webcontrols that could highlight the current page. I used JQuery selector to apply style as shown below. Solution very specific to my scenario...

```
$('.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox .ms-core-listMenu-root > li > ul > li > ul > li.selected').css("background-color","#CEEDF9");
```

Comment: where did nyou place this code? inside master page?