# SharePoint Quick Launch item not highlighted on click

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation, url, quick-launch

There are a number of links to lists/document libraries in the SharePoint Quick Launch on the left of the screen.

All of the links are clickable and accessible, however, the 'News' item, when clicked is not being highlighted in the menu.

Highlighted:

[image: Highlighted]

Non-Highlighted:

[image]

I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146017/quick-launch-highlight-current-page) post for which the user applied jQuery to the menu:

```
$('.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox .ms-core-listMenu-root > li > ul > li > ul > li.selected').css("background-color","#CEEDF9");
```

Where should I apply this code? In the Master Page through SharePoint Designer 2013?

I am using Sharepoint Collaboration 2013.

Comment: Make sure the link in the quick launch is the full path to the library with the view.

Comment: As Patrick mentions, it needs to be the full path and will usually end with `.aspx`. You shouldn't need to add any code.